# Decrypt Netbeans connection's encrypted passwords

Tags: encryption, netbeans, netbeans-8

Using Netbeans 8 on Windows 8;

I have ftp and ssh connections stored in my Netbeans that I lost from my password manager, so I am now trying to extract them from Netbeans but it's harder than I expected.

I exported the stored connections using options > export > Keyring & Passwords, I then obtained a text file called win32.properties that stores the connections, but they are encrypted.
As these exports are meant to import on another computer, I didn't expect the connections to be encrypted. How can the other Netbeans installation decrypt them? Is there a global Netbeans decryption key?

I would like to know if there is a way how I can run the decryption by myself.

Comment: 1) Always keep backups.  2) Do not lose your passwords; write them on a piece of paper kept away from your computer.  3) A global Netbeans key would be a huge security hole, so I doubt that it exists.

Comment: thanks for the advice. About your doubts at (3), see, from one Netbeans you can export the passwords to this file, and then import them in any other Netbeans. So I don't understand how else they could do that without a global key. Maybe someone could explain this to us